# App back from backround, after install from google play

Tags: java, android

What can be the reason for the fact that after installing the app from the play store, after switching to the background mode (home button) when I launch the app (app icon), it restarts from new, it does not enter the foreground (back from background). Once it kills the process and restarts it is ok every time.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing a few concepts here.

1)When you click on an icon to start an app, the default behavior is to launch the launcher activity, regardless of if an instance of your app is already running.  You can override this behavior in the manifest by setting the launch mode to singleTop or singleTask instead of standard.

2)Is it killing the process in the background?  Possibly.  Any app which is not the foreground activity may be killed at any time.  You need to be able to relaunch yourself by writing sufficient info to the bundle in onSaveInstanceState and reading it in on onRestoreInstanceState.  But it also may not be and may just be launching a new instance of the Activity.  These are two distinct cases, as killing the process means that singletons and other data objects will have been lost, whereas if the process was not killed they can still be accessed.

Comment: What is the difference because I only have a problem the first time I run it after installing it from google play. When I close the app and restart it, there is no such problem.

Comment: There is no difference here between being installed from Play or from some other means.  The app itself has no idea how it was installed.